# IIS8.5 Set cross domain available between HTTPS website

Tags: .net, api, ssl, iis-8.5

I've got an API for the authentication with a SSL certificate. If I try to use it through another API with a SSL certificate, I've got an error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxx.mydomain.com/v2/auth/token. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://yyyy.mydomain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

I can't use a wildcard for that.

I try to use that but it's only work for HTTP:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <clear />           
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only allow one origin entry per response, you'll need to inspect the `Origin` header in the pre-flight request to see if you want to allow it or not, and then write the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header value accordingly.

The easiest way in IIS 7.0+ is probably to write a custom handler and register it to handle OPTIONS requests to the `/v2/auth/` uri path.

I haven't written IIS extensions in a while, so this is a crude attempt at allowing any `Origin` within the same namespace (`mydomain.com`):

```
public class MultipleOriginHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    { 
        Uri origin;
        if(String.Compare(ctx.Request.HttpMethod,"OPTIONS",true) != 0)
            return; // not an OPTIONS request, 

        if(!Uri.TryCreate(ctx.Request.Headers.Get("Origin"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out origin))
            return; // failed to extract Origin URI

        if(origin.Host.EndsWith(".mydomain.com") || origin.Host == "mydomain.com"){
            // Request came from one of our own sites, let's allow it 
            ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",String.Format("{0}://{1}",origin.Scheme,origin.Host));
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Only alternative I can think of is to do something similar with the [`URL Rewrite` module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

If you want to allow requests based on whether it's authenticated, and not whether the origin falls within a certain host namespace, you could do that as well:

```
if(ctx.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
    // Request was authenticated 
    ctx.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",String.Format("{0}://{1}",origin.Scheme,origin.Host));
}
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that this authentication API will be used by our customers and we can't exactly know the other domains that call this API.

Comment: So... you don't want to block any domain but you won't use a wildcard? Do you see how that might be a problem? :)

Comment: The authentication API will be "public" (use by our customers) so I don't see how a wildcard will be resolve this problem (except maybe for my exemple)

Comment: @Pierre-AntoineDOUCHET Updated answer